# Spring Security LDAP authentication: exception while not specifying OUs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate with LDAP and spring security. While trying it the following way:

```
<security:ldap-server
    url="ldap://mydomain.de:389/dc=mydomain,dc=de" manager-dn="***"
    manager-password="***" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(&amp;(&amp;(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))(sAMAccountName={0}))">
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.ldap.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); nested exception is javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name ''
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:385)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name ''
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:322)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363)
    ... 52 more
```

But when I change the LDAP server url to:

```
"ldap://mydomain.de:389/OU=Users,OU=DE,dc=mydomain,dc=de" manager-dn="***"
```

it works. This is not the best solution for me because there are users outside the OUs too.
Why do I have to add the OUs to make it work? Is there any better way that includes all users (in the root path)?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try without context : "ldap://mydomain.de:389" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so today I finally found a solution to this:

As described [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/50755-setting-java-naming-referral-using-namespace-configuration), you have to define a contextSource bean. My xml now looks like this:

```
    <bean id="contextSource"
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://mydomain.de:389/dc=mydomain,dc=de" />
        <property name="userDn" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />

        <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="java.naming.referral">
                    <value>follow</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
   </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:ldap-authentication-provider
                user-search-filter="sAMAccountName={0}" server-ref="contextSource" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

The contextSource bean replaces the ldap-server tag.
The main difference is the "follow" value for java.naming.referral, which causes spring to follow the server reference returned by AD @Ludovic Poitou was [talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39786946/6899471).

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Active Directory service has multiple forests in different servers. When you point down to the OU, the result set is in a single server.
When you point to the domain, the server returns you some entries, but also a reference to the other servers to which you should continue to search.